# Eclipse neon, stopped with exit code=-1073740791

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to reinstall eclipse and add:

```
 -vm C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\javaw.exe.
```

See [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qc7Hf.jpg).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please explain your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the rules for specifying the virtual machine for eclipse as found [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini):

> **Note the format of the -vm option - it is important to be exact:**
>
> - The -vm option and its value (the path) must be on separate lines.
> - The value must be the full absolute or relative path to the Java executable, not just to the Java home directory.
> - The -vm option must occur after the other Eclipse-specific options (such as -product, --launcher.*, etc), but before the -vmargs option, since everything after -vmargs is passed directly to the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

Experiencing the same problem here, running Eclipse Neon.2 and JRE 1.8.0_121 on MS Windows 10.
If I specify a JVM in eclipse.ini (putting the -vm option and the javaw.exe pathname on separate lines in the right position, as Carlos Heuberger correctly suggests), eclipse crashes at startup with exit code=-1073740791, before opening the interface, but after initializing the workspace.

If I run Eclipse again, the interface opens and I can start working, but it is likely to crash after a while, apparently in a random way.
If I remove the -vm option from eclipse.ini and set JAVA_HOME and PATH in the environment, Eclipse seems to work fine; of course, this might cause problems to other applications on your system.

I think I eventually found the solution to the problem: the eclipse.ini file coming with the distribution has the JVM option **-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8** duplicated: simply remove the second instance and it will work like a charm!

Comment: I have two `-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8` and Eclipse works fine

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov - You are right. I checked with other people and myself on PCs with a similar configuration and they don't suffer from the same problem. I don't know what's wrong with my PC, I can simply tell you that removing such duplicated line solved the problem. It apparently makes littlle or no sense, but so it seems...