# Eclipse wont run why?

Tags: java, eclipse

[image]

Hello it seems like everytime when i lunch Eclipse it shows me this poppup and idk how to fix it i checked the JVM and the SDK everything is in order what should i do ?? at 1st it was another issue this was the 1st poppup :

```
version 1.8.0_381 of the JVM is not suitble for this product. Version :17 or greater is required
```

but then when i configured the env path the shown screenshot now keeps preventing me from using Eclipse

i thought that configuring the env path was the problem but it wasnt

Comment: Add all information as text not as image

Comment: Set the -vm option to the actual Java installation, not the shim you're currently using.

Comment: Better use the Java that is shipped with Eclipse instead of a Java that is installed in your system.

Comment: Most Eclipse downloads include a suitable Java and default to run with that - you should use one of those and not try to change the Java.

Answer (score 0):

As other commenters have stated here, use either the JVM that is bundled with Eclipse, or, as I recommend, install Temurin JDK 17 (https://adoptium.net/temurin/releases/).

When installing it, install the JAVA_HOME path option too.

Also, refer to this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42145921/18121299